# Polling many Git branches in one Jenkins CI job

Tags: git, jenkins, polling

I have a jenkins job, which build the project from git branch. Branch is set by build parameters.

In our repository we have more than 20 branches. Can I do something to set Jenkins to build a job after any commits? not for all branches, but for list of 5 selected branches.

I found a way to create git hooks, but it can affect another jobs with the same repository, that I do not want to trigger. Only my job should be triggered with branch that was last changed.